# blueimp jQueryFileUpload file[] - How to get width and height of image for display or limit them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, widget, jquery-file-upload

I use the Basic Plus UI version of blueimp jQuery-File-Upload for Upload images (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).
My wish is an output of the width and height of the image in addition to the file size and a minimal limitation of image size when uploading.

While searching on this page I found a script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781312/blueimp-fileupload-check-the-image-width-and-height-before-upload) from v1pr that output a message if you choose a too small image size. That works well.

But I would like to abort the upload process when closing the message.
And how do I get the image size (width x height) spent right next to the file size?

**In addition to listing of the file size I would like to have the picture size of the picture listed.**

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve You may also want to include things you have tried so far.

Comment: Here is an example to work with. Since BlueImp uses a few extra libraries to parse / load the image, you will have to dig into them to see if you can extract the image dimensions when adding them. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/hz6ucxyf/

Comment: Looking here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/hz6ucxyf/ it appears that `loadImage()` can get `sourceWidth` and `sourceHeight`. Another option would be to load the image in a non-visible `<img>` tag and read it's `.width()` and `.height()`.